# Bootstrap 4 - .modal is not a function

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I'm using plain Javascript along with Bootstrap, and am getting this error. I've looked at many different questions and none seem to work for me. I downloaded Jquery, Popper, and Bootstrap with npm, and have added the min scripts at the bottom of my body:

```
<div id="success-delete" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Success!</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Template successfully deleted.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

    <script src="/js/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/js/popper.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="/js/template-section.js" defer></script>
```

As you can see, I'm loading the jquery before bootstrap. When a function is called in my Javascript, I want the modal to appear:

```
/* template-section.js */
class TemplateSection {
    constructor(...) {
        ...
        this.successModal = document.querySelector('#success-delete');
    }

    _removeTemplate(e) {
        const success = this.deleteCallback(e.currentTarget.previousSibling.getAttribute('src'));
        if (success) {
            this.container.removeChild(e.currentTarget.parentNode);
            this.successModal.modal('show');
        } else {
            // do something
        }
     }

 }
```

I've also tried changing the modal options to {show : true}, but that's not working. Printing out this.successModal gives me the correct element, but it doesn't appear to have the function modal.

Edit: I also know for a fact that the bootstrap.min.js file I have has modals included - I tried activating the modal by a button click and it works fine. It's getting the javascript to recognize the modal that's the problem.

Edit 2: Fixed! See answer below.

Comment: Try to load Jquery and bootstrap library using CDN
`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>`                                                                                                                                    


`<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I would do that, but I've learned that's not as fast or scalable in the long-term... I'm using npm specifically so I can keep bootstrap in my dev environment with other modules.

Comment: I also just tried that on a whim, and it didn't work :(

Comment: " Thanks for you reply. I would do that, but I've learned that's not as fast or scalable in the long-term " Actually is the other way around, that is the whole point of a CDN, I'll advise you to research into the topic.  Said that, please open your browser debug tools and check if the files are being loaded properly in the network tab

Comment: They are being loaded properly, thank you. I didn't realize CDN is faster. I thought I did research on the topic, but I guess not enough. Any idea why the JS isn't working?

Answer (score 1):

Fixed by using `$('#success-delete')` instead of the object declared from documentSelector. Not really sure why, but it's working!

Comment: Bootstrap's modal is a jQuery plugin, so trying to call it on what `document.querySelector` returns won't work. If you use `console.log()` for each of the objects you get from `$('#success-delete')` and `document.querySelector`, you'll see the difference.

Comment: If you want to use `this.successModal`, you can just wrap it in a jquery function like this: `$(this.successModal).modal('show');`